# Merge/create over a full join

Tags: neo4j, cypher

In Neo4j browser, with the code:

```
MATCH  (a:VAR1)<--(s:VARX {id: 'MYID'})-->(b:VAR2) RETURN a, b;
```

In the graph view I just see 6 nodes

```
VAR1 id:A
VAR1 id:B
VAR1 id:C
VAR2 id:X
VAR2 id:Y
VAR2 id:Z
```

But in the table view I see all the possible combinations:

```
VAR1.id VAR2.id
A       X
A       Y
A       Z
B       X
B       Y
B       Z
C       X
C       Y
C       Z
```

this is the full join that I want

however based on this I would like to create a node for each single combination

```
VARY
{id1:"A",id2:"X"}
{id1:"A",id2:"Y"}
{id1:"A",id2:"Z"}
{id1:"B",id2:"X"}
{id1:"B",id2:"Y"}
{id1:"B",id2:"Z"}
{id1:"C",id2:"X"}
{id1:"C",id2:"Y"}
{id1:"C",id2:"Z"}
```

Also, all of these nodes need a relationship with their 2 source nodes

```
[VARY {id1:"A",id2:"X"}] -FROM-> [VAR1 {id:"A"}]
[VARY {id1:"A",id2:"X"}] -FROM-> [VAR2 {id:"X"}]
```

I tried so many combinations with UNWIND, so many FOREACH, with no luck, any hint would be appreciated. Thanks for your time.

---

Better explanation on why I need this

I need 3 informations to be linked together

```
VAR1 VAR2 VAR3
A    X    M
A    Y    P
A    Z    O
B    X    M
B    Y    Q
B    Z    O
C    X    M
C    Y    R
C    Z    O
```

As you can see, I need as structure the cartesian product of VAR1 and VAR2
However VAR3 can contains different values based for each combination of VAR1 and VAR2, the correct visualisation would in fact be in a pivot table like this

```
    X   Y   Z
A   M   P   O
B   M   Q   O   
C   M   R   O
```

Going to cypher, I have VAR1, VAR2, VAR3 stored in independent nodes, in order not to lose the traceability of connection I'm creating a node connecting the 3 informations.

Basically, VARX is filtering these data and I have:

```
VARX - [TOVAR1] -> VAR1(a)
VARX - [TOVAR1] -> VAR1(b)
VARX - [TOVAR1] -> VAR1(c)

VARX - [TOVAR2] -> VAR2(x)
VARX - [TOVAR2] -> VAR2(y)
VARX - [TOVAR2] -> VAR2(z)

VARX - [TOVAR3] -> VAR3(M)
VARX - [TOVAR3] -> VAR3(O)
VARX - [TOVAR3] -> VAR3(P)
VARX - [TOVAR3] -> VAR3(Q)
VARX - [TOVAR3] -> VAR3(R)
```

So I for cell (1,1) need a relationship of VAR1(a) and VAR2(x) and VAR3(M) to be filled in another independent node that can store the triple (a,x,m). Same for all the VAR1_n * VAR2_n couples (VAR1,VAR2), in this case 3*3=9.

Does it makes sense to you?

Comment: Can you explain why you want to do this? It would add a lot of redundant information to the DB, which is not advisable unless there is a real need.

Comment: Hi again, @cybersam ! the idea is to create derived nodes and link them back to their source. for each of these I then want to set more labels to the node later on. I tried some kind of foreach combination like FOREACH( nodes in VAR1 | FOREACH(nodes in VAR2 | MERGE VARY { id1: var1.id, id2 var2.id } - [:FROM] -> VAR1{id:var1.id}, VARY { id1: var1.id, id2 var2.id } - [:FROM] -> VAR2{id:var2.id} ))

but I'm failing to find a proper syntax that works.

Comment: Although what you want to do is possible, it is generally an anti-pattern to store data redundantly. Not only does it consume more storage, but it makes your code a lot more complex. Every addition/deletion/update of redundant data in one place requires you to write additional code to make sure all other copies and the rest of the DB stays consistent (perhaps atomically, if multiple transactions can occur simultaneously). You need to have a real need to justify redundancy (like a critical use case that requires the utmost speed that would otherwsie not be possible).

Comment: @cybersam I got the syntax to work, but since you are raising a good point I'm adding more info so you can take a look why I need this :)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to represent this table:

```
VAR1 VAR2 VAR3
A    X    M
A    Y    P
A    Z    O
B    X    M
B    Y    Q
B    Z    O
C    X    M
C    Y    R
C    Z    O
```

You can use a non-redundant data model with unique nodes. For example:

```
(:Var1)-[:T1]->(:Var3)<-[:T2]-(:Var2)
```

Here is some sample Cypher code for creating the (unique) nodes and relationships:

```
UNWIND [
  {id1: 'A', id2: 'X', id3: 'M'},
  {id1: 'A', id2: 'Y', id3: 'P'},
  {id1: 'A', id2: 'Z', id3: 'O'},
  {id1: 'B', id2: 'X', id3: 'M'},
  {id1: 'B', id2: 'Y', id3: 'Q'},
  {id1: 'B', id2: 'Z', id3: 'O'},
  {id1: 'C', id2: 'X', id3: 'M'},
  {id1: 'C', id2: 'Y', id3: 'R'},
  {id1: 'C', id2: 'Z', id3: 'O'}
] AS d
MERGE (v1:Var1 {id: d.id1})
MERGE (v2:Var2 {id: d.id2})
MERGE (v3:Var3 {id: d.id3})
MERGE p1=(v1)-[:T1]->(v3)
MERGE p2=(v2)-[:T2]->(v3)
RETURN p1, p2
```